# Python 2.7 W7 - how to write result of a map reduce funcion to a file

Tags: python

I have a "print result" (that is fine) exactly like this:

> 'Mixer Audio|Mixer Video' : 2, 'Tecnico Audio|Operatore Televideo' : 4, ' |Tecnico Video' : 4, 'Tecnico Audio|Tecnico Audio' : 7, 'Mixer Audio|Mixer Audio' : 3

I tried to export results to a txt file:

```
 with open('s.txt', 'w') as line:
    for row in results:
        print row
        line.write("%s\n" % str(row))
```

This is what I found in s.txt:

```
Mixer Audio|Mixer Video
Tecnico Audio|Operatore Televideo
|Tecnico Video
Tecnico Audio|Tecnico Audio
Mixer Audio|Mixer Audio
```

I really need help from experts.

Answer (score 0):

Your `results` is a dictionary, and your code is only writing the keys to a file.
You should also write the values.

```
results = {'Mixer Audio|Mixer Video' : 2, 'Tecnico Audio|Operatore Televideo' : 4, ' |Tecnico Video' : 4, 'Tecnico Audio|Tecnico Audio' : 7, 'Mixer Audio|Mixer Audio' : 3}

with open('s.txt', 'w') as line:
    for key, value in results.iteritems():
        line.write("{}: {}\n".format(key, value))
```

Result:

```
Mixer Audio|Mixer Audio: 3
 |Tecnico Video: 4
Mixer Audio|Mixer Video: 2
Tecnico Audio|Operatore Televideo: 4
Tecnico Audio|Tecnico Audio: 7
```

You could also get all of the results on one line, similar to `print results`:

```
results = {'Mixer Audio|Mixer Video' : 2, 'Tecnico Audio|Operatore Televideo' : 4, ' |Tecnico Video' : 4, 'Tecnico Audio|Tecnico Audio' : 7, 'Mixer Audio|Mixer Audio' : 3}
with open('s.txt', 'w') as line:
    line.write(str(results))
```

Result:

> {'Mixer Audio|Mixer Audio': 3, ' |Tecnico Video': 4, 'Mixer Audio|Mixer Video': 2, 'Tecnico Audio|Operatore Televideo': 4, 'Tecnico Audio|Tecnico Audio': 7}